# How to request an image with whichever file extension is available using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, function

I need to load an image file and I'm trying to write a short code to just get whatever version is available (first .svg and if not available then .png), so I came up with this React snippet:

*Apologies in advance for butchering code formatting and possibly other beginner's mistakes*

```js
let serviceLogo = (typeof this.props.service != undefined || typeof this.props.service != "undefined" ) 
? 
 (
  require( `./path/logo-` + this.props.service + `.svg`) != null 
    ? require(`.path/logo-` + this.props.service + `.svg`) 
    : require(`.path/logo-` + this.props.service + `.png` )
 ) 
: "" ;
```

which will then just be called here

`<img src={serviceLogo} />`

It works fine if the file is `.svg`. But I'm missing something because if the image file extension is `.png` instead I get the error:

`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './logo-whateverfilename.svg'`

How can I fix the code to give me a PNG file if an SVG version doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

It gives an error because `require` is trying to import file that doesn't exists before you check if that file exists or not.

```
require( `./path/logo-` + this.props.service + `.svg`) != null
```

you can try to encapsulate your code with try catch like this

```
let serviceLogo = '';

if (this.props.service) {
    try {
        serviceLogo = require( `./path/logo-` + this.props.service + `.svg`);
    } catch (error) {
        serviceLogo = require( `./path/logo-` + this.props.service + `.png`);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the image is SVG instead, your script gives me an error